# google chrome, close tab event listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension and I need to get the event when the tab is closed so I can fire of an post to a server. This is what I have atm.

```
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function (tabId) {
   alert(tabId);
});
```

But I can't get it to work. Anyone got any ideas?

Edit:

When I'm running it, it says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onRemoved' of undefined

Edit2: manifest.json

```
{
"name": "WebHistory Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "storing webhistory",
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*"],
            "js": ["jquery-1.7.min.js","myscript.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "permissions" : ["tabs"]
}
```

Comment: Looks like the correct way to go - [according to the docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onRemoved) any errors ?

Comment: When I'm running it, it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onRemoved' of undefined"

Comment: So your code is probably in a wrong place. Is it executed on a background page? Do you have permissions for `tabs` set up? Please provide your `manifest.json` settings.

Comment: it's a content script, and I have the tabs permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `chrome.tabs` API in content scripts:

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot: Use
>   chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension)

[source](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)

What you need to do is to establish communication between content script and background page. Background page has access to `chrome.tabs` API:

> These limitations aren't as bad as they sound. Content scripts can
>   indirectly use the chrome.* APIs, get access to extension data, and
>   request extension actions by exchanging messages with their parent
>   extension.

[source](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html)

Everything is in the first five paragraphs of content script documentation.